# Assigning formula via cells.formula and error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I got the error related to the code below. The weird part is, I am able to access and write to the cells.formula property just find in immediate, and I was able to run the formula just fine as well in immediate. The error is "Application-defined or object-defined error". Since I have no clue what is causing the issue, I pasted the entire code here to see if anyone see something that may be causing it. It's weird....

```
' This function adds a column to an existing table if the table does not already has the function, or updates the table with the new values as needed
Public Function AddAssocStds(objSheet As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rowHeader As Integer
    Dim CombDes As Integer
    Dim AssocStd As Integer
    Dim SAP As Variant
    Dim Stockcode As Variant
    Dim Mincom As Variant
    Dim WriteAssocStd As String

    ' Defines my header row
    rowHeader = 1
    ' A specific row to look up in an existing table
    CombDes = -1
    ' This is the write row
    AssocStd = -1
    i = 1

    ' Speeding up the run, speed play
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Registers the columns in the sheet correctly first
    For i = 1 To objSheet.Cells(rowHeader, objSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Select Case Cells(rowHeader, i).value
            Case "CombinedDescription"
                CombDes = i
            Case "AssocStds"
                AssocStd = i
            Case "SAP"
                SAP = objSheet.Range(objSheet.Cells(rowHeader + 1, i), objSheet.Cells(objSheet.UsedRange.Count, i)).value
            Case "Stockcode"
                Stockcode = objSheet.Range(objSheet.Cells(rowHeader + 1, i), objSheet.Cells(objSheet.UsedRange.Count, i)).value
            Case "Mincom"
                Mincom = objSheet.Range(objSheet.Cells(rowHeader + 1, i), objSheet.Cells(objSheet.UsedRange.Count, i)).value
        End Select
    Next

    ' Determines which column to write to - either inserts after combdes column or make a new column
    If AssocStd = -1 Then
        If CombDes = -1 Then
            AssocStd = objSheet.Cells(rowHeader, objSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Else
            objSheet.Range(Cells(1, CombDes + 1), Cells(1, CombDes + 1)).EntireColumn.Insert
            AssocStd = CombDes + 1
        End If
    End If

    ' Writes the header for the new column
    objSheet.Cells(rowHeader, AssocStd).value = "AssocStds"

    ' Resets the counter
    i = 1

    ' Loops throught the entire column
    For i = 1 To objSheet.UsedRange.Count - rowHeader
        If NotNull(CStr(SAP(i, 1))) Then
            WriteAssocStd = AssocStdsGen(CStr(SAP(i, 1)))
        Else
            WriteAssocStd = "-1"
        End If

        If WriteAssocStd = "-1" And NotNull(CStr(Stockcode(i, 1))) Then
            WriteAssocStd = AssocStdsGen(CStr(Stockcode(i, 1)))
        Else
            WriteAssocStd = "-1"
        End If

        If WriteAssocStd = "-1" And NotNull(CStr(Mincom(i, 1))) Then
            WriteAssocStd = AssocStdsGen(CStr(Mincom(i, 1)))
        Else
            WriteAssocStd = "-1"
        End If

        ' This is where the problem happens, when writing as a formula, it doesn't work...
        If WriteAssocStd = "-1" Then
            objSheet.Cells(i + rowHeader, AssocStd).Formula = "=IF(UPPER([@Standard RR]) <> " & Chr(34) & "NON-STD" & Chr(34) & ", [@Standard RR] &" & Chr(34) & "-" & Chr(34) & "&[@PlanNo] & " & Chr(34) & "." & Chr(34) & "& TEXT([@SheetNo], " & Chr(34) & "00" & Chr(34) & "), [@Standard RR])"
        Else
            objSheet.Cells(i + rowHeader, AssocStd).value = WriteAssocStd
        End If
    Next

    AddAssocStds = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Additional note:

- The formula does work in excel by itself as evidenced by the rows that did not prompt the error
- The error seems to only occur at the last row. I have a weird feeing it may be related

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at the formula concatenation to make sure the formula is valid.

Comment: The formula, ran in immediate, shows as "=IF(UPPER([@Standard RR]) <> "NON-STD", [@Standard RR] &"-"&[@PlanNo] & "."& TEXT([@SheetNo], "00"), [@Standard RR])". Does not appear to be a syntax issue.

Comment: I can reproduce the error if the target cell is not in the table. Try `debug.print`-ing the address of `objSheet.Cells(i + rowHeader, AssocStd)` to confirm it is in the table.

Comment: Ahhh!! I was using usedrange.count and that grabbed more than what is actually there. I revised the counters, and it didn't bump an error out anymore. So I guess I would need to do an entirerow.insert to make this work if I indeed want to add rows?